SelectInput with conditional dataframe
I want to make a shiny app in which I select different dataframes to visualize. Then I want to select a filter on this same dataframe. The point is that I want the selectInput to show the filter options according to the available values ​​of the selected dataframe.
This is my code and the lines with # show my unsuccessful attempt to do this.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)



ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Planejamento de compras"), #título do aplicativo
        dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(
                radioButtons(inputId = "cronograma", label = "Qual ano deseja pesquisar?",  choices = c("Cronograma_2022", "Cronograma_2023"), selected = "Cronograma_2023"),
                selectizeInput(inputId = "setor", label = "Selecione o setor:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
            )
        ),
        dashboardBody(
                fluidRow(
                box(DT::DTOutput("table"),)
            )
        )
                
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
        cronodata <- reactive({
            if(input$cronograma == "Cronograma_2022"){ 
                table0 <- iris[Species == "setosa" | Species =="versicolor" ,] #different dataframes with diferent values in Column "Species"
                                
            }else if(input$cronograma == "Cronograma_2023"){
                table0 <- iris [Species == "virginica" | Species =="versicolor",] #different dataframes with diferent values in Column "Species"

            }else{
                break
            }
            #table0 <- table0[Species %in% input$setor,]
            setDT(table0)
            return(table0)
        
        })


        #updateSelectizeInput(session, "setor", choices = unique(sort(cronodata()[,Species,])), server = TRUE)
        
        output$table <- DT::renderDT(cronodata(), 
            
            )
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)


Here is a working (minimal) example
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)



ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "data_frame", label = "Data frame",  choices = c("Cronograma_2022", "Cronograma_2023"), selected = "Cronograma_2023"),
  selectizeInput(inputId = "specie", label = "Select specie", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  tableOutput("table")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cronodata <- reactive({
    switch(
      input$data_frame,
      Cronograma_2022 = filter(iris, Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor")),
      Cronograma_2023 = filter(iris, Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor")),
      stop()
    )
  })
  
  observe(
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "specie", choices = unique(cronodata()$Species))
  )
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(input$specie)
    cronodata() |>
      filter(Species == input$specie)
  })
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)



Thanks Johan, I can already see the update of InputSelectize. However, in the example you created, the table does not update when I select one of the options that are available in inputSelectize.

For example: If I select the species setosa in inputselectize (in this case in dataframe Cronograma_2022) the table does not update. I would like it to update showing only the rows containing Species setosa.

Changes added :)

Thanks Johan! If it's not a problem, would it be possible to add another selectinput whose text box updates as the option in the other selectinput is selected?

You're asking for the same logic that is already in the answer. I think that for simple changes like this one is better if you use the "Shiny assistant" https://shiny.posit.co/blog/posts/shiny-assistant/
